# Beautify the Python Nested Dictionary Code

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

**Output :**

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "overall": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "created",
        "calendar_interval": "day",
        "time_zone": 3
      },
      "aggs": {
        "series_attribute": {
          "terms": {
            "field": 2
          },
          "aggs": {
            "types_count": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Input :**
aggregation1 =

```
{
                "types_count": {
                            "value_count": {
                                "field": 1
                            }
                        }
            }
```

aggregation2 =

```
{
            "series_attribute": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": 2
                }
            }
        }
```

aggregation3 =

```
{
            "overall": {
                "date_histogram": {
                    "field": "created",
                    "calendar_interval": "day",
                    "time_zone": 3
                }
            }
        }



countResponse,termResponse,dateResponse = {},{},{}
countResponse["aggs"] = aggregation1
termResponse["aggs"] = aggregation2
dateResponse["aggs"] = aggregation3
aggregation2["series_attribute"]["aggs"] = aggregation1
aggregation3["overall"]["aggs"] = termResponse["aggs"]
#print(json.dumps(dateResponse))
```

This code works but I am not sure if the code can be modified to look better.I have nested 3 dictionaries  one inside the another but I do not like the way in which we are accessing the keys and adding the key-value pair.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. `json.dumps` supports many features like indentation, sorting keys and more. Look into [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) and then edit your question accordingly. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26243238).

Comment: No, that line is now commented out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the code like so to make it more readable.

```
output = { "aggs" : aggregation3 }
aggregation3["overall"]["aggs"] = aggregation2
aggregation2["series_attribute"]["aggs"] = aggregation1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to assign countResponse,termResponse,dateResponse variables,
you could do something like this:

```
dateResponse = {"aggs":aggregation3}
aggregation2["series_attribute"] = countResponse = {"aggs":aggregation1}
aggregation3["overall"] = termResponse = {"aggs":aggregation2}
```